# The title displayed on the search engine is false WORDPRESS

Tags: wordpress, yoast, ionos

I'm new to the world of WordPress. I've installed the YOAST SEO extension, and in the settings, I've configured the site to be called "Lottie - Restaurant cuisine fraîche." [settings yoast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws84N.png)

However, it's not displaying like that in the search engine. I don't understand why; maybe I'm modifying it in the wrong place ? [search engine title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmEmv.png)

I've also changed it in Settings -> General -> Site Title, but it's still not correct. [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxLfA.png)

Thanks.

I tried to change the title in yoast. I tried to change the title in basic settings. I tried to change the title of the website in IONOS.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely normal. Google is known to change the title of the search result depending on what the crawler thinks the title should be. This also depends on the search result context. If you do a `site:` query, it might actually show the original title while if you rank for a keyword, it might show a different title for that keyword's result.

For more information, follow [this link](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/title-link?hl=en&sjid=5373621449843146608-AP&visit_id=638404742048291702-1551327034&rd=1).

I do not think you can mitigate this by your own. However, having a short and relevant title might tell the crawlers to use the original title instead of generating a title by their own.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

So if i put a shorter title, it might work ?

This is litteraly the name of the restaurant, in the website we found it multiple time, it is pertinent ?

Comment: As for the restaurant name in title being pertinent, I guess it is, because that's what the web page is about. There are more things you might want to follow though. Please check the link I posted in my answer. It helps to have title, proper h1 tag and JSON schema as well.